# Href extraction by Web crawler using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I've written a code which extracts all the links from the url specified. I took this idea from an online video tutorial. When I tried with nytimes.com, if worked out. But when I tried with yell.com, I had an error thrown: "Error: HTTP Error 416: Requested Range Not Satisfiable - http://www.yell.com/". What technique should I adopt in order to bypass this.

```
import urllib.parse;
import urllib;
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;

##url = "http://nytimes.com";
url = "http://www.yell.com/";

urls = [url];   
visited = [url];

while(len(urls) > 0):

    try:
        htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read();

        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext);

        urls.pop(0);
        print(len(urls));

        for tag in soup.findAll('a',href=True) :
            tag['href'] = urllib.parse.urljoin(url,tag['href']);
            if(url in tag['href'] and tag['href'] not in visited) :
                urls.append(tag['href']);
                visited.append(tag['href']);

    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print("Error: " + str(e)
              + " - " + url);

print(visited);
```

Comment: a tip: use `set()` for `visited`, it is much faster. And I have impression, that yell.com is loaded by javascript, hence might be your problems.

Comment: set() for visited? I couldn't understand. Can you be a little brief? Is using "Selenium" a good choice to grab javascript loaded pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that yell.com is detecting irregular activity. If you try to do this scraping visually using selenium, the way it would load Javascript:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
driver.set_window_size(100000, 200000)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5) # wait to load

# at this point, if you see the Firefox window that opened you will see the message

# Anyway, if you manage to get pass trough that blocking, you could load BeautifulSoup this way: 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Yea... The browser is blocked. Is there any way to by pass the block? Is there any package which will solve the problem?

Comment: you could try using different drivers with Selenium, for example, Chrome, Opera... Or try using mechanize to set different agents. http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/